# Update every row in a SQL table with preg match?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, preg-replace

I am making some big changes to my database, so I need to replace a lot of text with some new text, but only when a certain word exist.

```
  Table
*-----------------------------------------------*
|    id    |    name   |    adress   |   town   |
*-----------------------------------------------*
```

I have a table like this. I want to replace "adress" and "town" in every row of the table, where "town = new york" (for example).

So every time the text "new york" occurs in "town", both adress and town should be replaced with something else. Only one time- when i run the script.

Can anyone help me with this? I imagine i could use preg match and replace function from PHP in some way do to this, or can it be done purely with a SQL command?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE theTable
SET name = 'xxx',
    adress = 'xxx'
WHERE town LIKE '%new york%'
```

Or, `WHERE UPPER(town) like UPPER('%new york%')` to be case insensitive.

Comment: I think this is an accurate an answer as can be given without @2by giving more or clearer information.

Comment: Dumb question, but is that format of LIKE case insensitive? `New York`, `new York`, `New York`, `new york` ?

Comment: @Smamatti this depends on the database system (case sensitive for MySQL, as Francois B. addresses, I believe Oracle and PostgreSQL are case sensitive, SQL Server case insensitive); you can google for: 'site:stackoverflow.com sql like case sensitive'...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support regular expressions, but it has a **like** operator (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for details) which supports the placeholders "%" and "_", where "%" matches any number of characters (even 0), and "_" matches exactly one character (similar to the "*" and "?" filename wildcards). So to find strings containing "New York" at the beginning, use

```
where town like "New York%"
```

for strings containing "New York" anywhere in the string

```
where town like "%New York%"
```

Comment: Yes it does. look up `RLIKE`/`REGEXP` in the MySQL docs. Though, it is not PCRE which can be a pain.